# If else operator

Tags: r, function, if-statement

Could someone please just tell me the switch in R that returns the second argument if true and the third if false?

I have searched for `switch` and `if else function` and I have looked through the documentation but when using ubiquitous terms like if and else it seems very hard to identify a solution.

I am looking for something like:

```
f(TRUE,1,2); f(FALSE,1,2)
[1] 1
[1] 2
```

I am working on reading through the documentation of Julia which has made me aware of some of my gaps in knowledge in R.  In Julia there is an operator available.

```
(true  ? 1 : 2) 
1
(false ? 1 : 2)
2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply `ifelse`

```
ifelse(TRUE,1,2)
## [1] 1
ifelse(FALSE,1,2)
## [1] 2
```

Comment: don't forget the possibility `if (condition) 1 else 2` for scalar tests

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
 ifelse(condition, 1, 2)
```

Oddly enough, it is named `ifelse()` :-)

PS And while we're at it, do not use `T` and `F`, use `TRUE` and `FALSE`.  Every self-respecting style-guide suggests so.

Comment: Gar.  Thanks, I knew this one was going to make me look stupid :P

Comment: Happens. I have come to SO to look for something only to find it in an answer written by my younger self.

Comment: "Wow, that's really nice answer. Oh wait, it's mine!" :)